# (android)Sliding Menu to change Fragment, the List view has gone

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter, slidingmenu

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private ListView listView;

private ArrayList<MainViewItem> mainViewItems;
private MainViewListAdapter adapter;
public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mainViewItems = new ArrayList<MainViewItem>();

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

}

public void initData()
{
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("page", "1");

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("HTTP://link", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(response).getAsJsonArray();

            for(JsonElement obj : jArray )
            {
                PhotoBoxInfo cse = gson.fromJson( obj , PhotoBoxInfo.class);
                mainViewItems.add(new MainViewItem(cse));
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume(); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initData();
}

@Override  
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  
    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.PhotoBoxList);
    adapter = new MainViewListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mainViewItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        System.out.println(listView);
        System.out.println(adapter);

}
```

}}

Hi all.

I am now trying to create a sliding menu and with different fragment.
All the fragment contain a list view.

Once I debug the app, it can get the data from my Database and it can be shown on the fragment view.

But once I want to switch to the another fragment and then switch back.

The list view is disappear and cannot be shown any more.

I had google the problem, maybe it is related to the  / which is released.

But I still have no idea....

Please help me...

Thank You

Comment: moreover, the data is successful for receive every time.
I am quite sure it is not due to the network problem

Answer (score 0):

Finial I solved it by myself

```
public void initData()
{
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("page", "1");

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray jArray = parser.parse(response).getAsJsonArray();

            for(JsonElement obj : jArray )
            {
                PhotoBoxInfo cse = gson.fromJson( obj , PhotoBoxInfo.class);
                mainViewItems.add(new MainViewItem(cse));
            }
            adapter = new MainViewListAdapter(getActivity(),mainViewItems);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

It is because of the asynchronous http requests.

The Fragment reload but the data didn't received

I set the adapter after received the data